# C#, Need help to seperate one beginner program

Tags: c#

As beginner lesson I want to port this tutorial http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/create-simple-hidden-console-keylogger-c-sharp-0132757/ to a Windows Form Application.
This should show a user what keys are pressed inside a label called 'lblMessage'.

I have separeted the code now into two pieces.

Form1.cs

```
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public GlobalKeyHook hook = new GlobalKeyHook();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Origin
            // _hookID = SetHook(_proc);

            hook._hookID = hook.SetHook(_proc);

        }

        private void Form1_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Origin
            // UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);

            hook.UnhookWindowsEx(_hookID);

        }
    }
}
```

GlobalKeyHook.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.IO;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication3
{
    class GlobalKeyHook : Form
    {
        #region DLLs
        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
            LowLevelKeyboardProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
        public static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
            IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
        #endregion


        #region Fields and delegation
        private const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;
        private const int WM_KEYDOWN = 0x0100;
        private static LowLevelKeyboardProc _proc = HookCallback;
        public static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

        public delegate IntPtr LowLevelKeyboardProc(
        int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);
        #endregion

        public GlobalKeyHook()
        {
            IntPtr hookID = _hookID;
            LowLevelKeyboardProc proc = _proc;
        }

        static Form form = new Form();

        #region Methods
        private static IntPtr HookCallback(
            int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
        {
            if (nCode >= 0 && wParam == (IntPtr)WM_KEYDOWN)
            {
                int vkCode = Marshal.ReadInt32(lParam);
                Console.WriteLine((Keys)vkCode);
                form.Text = vkCode.ToString();
            }
            return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        }

        public static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelKeyboardProc proc)
        {
            using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
            using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
            {
                return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
                GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
            }
        }
        #endregion
    }
}
```

But I am not able to use the `public static IntPtr _hookID`, the method `SetHook()` or the DLL `UnhookWindowsHookEx` in the Form1 class. Is it not possible to use this "types" from another class?

Comment: Why is `GlobalKeyHook` a `Form`?  And why does it also *have* a `Form`?  This code is confusing.

Comment: It does have a form because I want to send information to the label from the GlobalKeyHook class. I am confused at the moment too. ;)

Comment: That form is never shown, though.  Maybe you plan on adding that feature later?  As a general word of advice, having placeholders in the code for not-yet-added features gets messy fast.  Keep the code as simple as possible and only add the features when it's time to add them.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure this will solve all your problems but may help you avoid a few of them down the line.

If this is .net 4.0 or higher your `SetWindowsHookEX()` call will likely return 0 (it failed) because .net no longer emulates a native module for managed dlls. To fix this you can add a DllImport for `LoadLibrary()` like this:

```
[DllImport("kernel32", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPStr)]string lpFileName);
```

Then somewhere before you call `SetWindowsHookEX()` do this:

```
IntPtr hinstDLL = UnsafeMethods.LoadLibrary("user32.dll");
```

and call `SetWindowsHookEX()` like this:

```
SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, proc,
            hinstDLL, 0);
```

Basically `SetWindowsHookEX()` needs a valid module handle which it verifies but never actually uses it. the reason to load `user32` is that since you are p/invoking functions from it you def have it.

Also, in your constructor just set it to IntPtr.Zero. No need make `_hookID` if you always are setting it to IntPtr.Zero. It is also worth noting that if the computer you are running this on has less than win7sp1 using IntPtr.Zero won't work (99% sure at least.)

I would strongly suggest you check out [This set of hooks](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C) They have a decent implementation of a hook library that you can easily extend however you want.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes I am using .NET 4.5.2. I will try your solution later, when I am back home.

Comment: I just tested the CodePlex Demo 2 but when I click a CheckBox an error message pops up. The download for Demo1 is blocked by the antivirus engine.

Comment: For your uses, sourcecode1 should have an implementation for hooks that is pretty similar to what you are already doing (you may want to change the `SetWindowsHookEX()` to be like I suggested. Just follow the 'using the code' section. Besides going through and working with getting the code up to date is a great way to learn about the inner workings of hooks and windows messages.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set your GlobalKeyHook class to `public class GlobalKeyHook`.

Comment: Thanks, yes I just tried it. The `: Form` is marked red with `static`. Without it looks good.

Comment: But I am still not able to get the `_hookID` when I try `hook._hookID`

Comment: IntelliSense marks the `_hook` red when I do `hook._hookID`